# Action line spreads across two lines when too much going on

Tags: bug, css

Pretty simple, mods see disruptive line breaks when we view a question that has been edited, has a pending suggested edit, and has at least one vote to close. The result is the vote to close count is detached and placed at the beginning of the next line.

[Here is an example](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45435/in-order-to-reproduce-a-display-bug) and here is what it looks like for a mod on Chrome 27 on OS 10.9 Mavericks beta:

[image]

And on Chrome 27 on OS 10.8.2 it's better but not perfect IMHO:

[image]

Comment: Anyone able to reproduce? I'm not seeing this behavior.

Comment: @Abby it seems to be another OS-specific thing. In OS X 10.8.2 - same version of Chrome (27) - they're all on one line, but the word 'flag' is dangerously close to the word 'edited' above Paul's avatar.

Comment: Yup, I'm seeing the "dangerously close" version.

Comment: I see the top version as well.

Comment: And here I thought it was because I was using a userscript that added too much to that line. Pretty sure this is a "tough luck, you're a moderator" issue.